# Search values of two textboxes in two excel columns

Tags: excel, vba

Need a macro that will search TextboxSearch value in "B" column-if found then search the TextboxSearch2 value in "C" column in the same row where TextboxSearch value was found. Bref, if "First name" found then check Lastname". 
I've tried this but got a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Private Sub CommandSearch_Click()
            Dim FindRow
            Dim cRow As String
            cRow = TextBoxSearch.Value
        Set FindRow = Sheets("Trainees").Range("B:B").find(What:=cRow, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If FindRow Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Record not found! Retry search.", vbInformation
                    UserForm_Initialize
                    Exit Sub
                End If
        With Sheets("Trainees")
            lastRow = .Range("B:P").find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            For CurRow = FirstRow To lastRow
                If .Range("B" & CurRow).Value = TextBoxSearch.Value And .Range("C" & CurRow).Value = TextBoxSearch2.Value Then
                    FindMatch = CurRow
                End If
            Next CurRow
        End With
'add the values to the userform
                Label = FindRow.Offset(0, -1)
                TextBoxFirstN.Value = FindRow.Offset.Value
                TextBoxLastN.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1)
                If FindRow.Offset(0, 2) = "Male" Then ChkBoxMale.Value = True
                If FindRow.Offset(0, 2) = "Female" Then ChkBoxFemale.Value = True
                TextBoxBirthTrainee.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module... `For CurRow = FirstRow To lastRow` has 3 undeclared variables in it.

Comment: Works perfectly but but cannot check value of TextBoxSearch2. if textboxsearch find its populate the user form.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand why you need the loop `For CurRow = FirstRow To lastRow` ? Will there a possibility that the value between TextBoxLastN.Value and TextBoxSearch2.Value different ? And also, where do you use the `FindMatch` variable  ?

Comment: Karma,
The idea is to search “ TextBoxSearch” text in column "B". if the text is found then check the “TextBoxSearch2” text matches with the text in column "C" of same of the text in column "B".
The macro will be used to search for the first name and last name of students in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Below macro works, but in case of 2 persons with the same first name, it has to populate data of the 1st person even if his Last name does not match with the TextBox Search2. I need assistance on "FindRow". Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandSearch_Click() 
  Dim Firstname, LastName, AName, i As Long, FindRow As Range, CorrectDetails As Boolean 
  Firstname = TextBoxSearch.Value 
  LastName = TextBoxSearch2.Value 
    With Sheets("Trainees") lrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
      For i = 7 To lrow 
        If Trim(.Range("B" & i).Value) = Trim(Firstname) Then 
        If Trim(.Range("C" & i).Value) = Trim(LastName) Then CorrectDetails = True 
          Set FindRow = .Range("B:B").Find(What:=Firstname, LookIn:=xlValues) 
             Label.Caption = FindRow.Offset(0, -1) TextBoxFirstN.Value = FindRow.Offset.Value 
             TextBoxLastN.Value = FindRow.Offset(0, 1) 
        End If 
      Next I
        If CorrectDetails = False Then 
           MsgBox "Record not found! Retry search." & vbCrLf & "Make sure you are searching in the right Database.", vbInformation 
           Exit Sub 
        End If 
   End With 
End Sub
```